# My array list keeps outputing the same list item if I click the add button with empty input

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So here is my question. I have this todolist aarray which works but the problem is it keeps repeating the same ouput if I click the button with empty output. I have added and if statement to prevent it but it seemd not doing anything. I guess my problem is in displayItems function but I don't know where. This is my code:

HTML:

```
<h2>Add an item to the list</h2>
<input type="text" id="addItemInput"><button class="addButton" onclick="events.addItem();">Add an item</button>
<ul id="todoList">

</ul>
```

JavaScript

Control section to add an item to the list and display it

```
var todoListArray = {
  todoList : [],
  addItems : function(todoItem){
    if(todoItem != ""){
       this.todoList.push({
           todoItem : todoItem 
      });
    }else{
      todoItem = "";
    }
  },
  displayItems : function(){
        var listParent = document.getElementById('todoList');

    for(var i=0;i<this.todoList.length;i++){
            var listItem = document.createElement('li');
            listItem.innerHTML = this.todoList[i].todoItem;
      listParent.appendChild(listItem);
    }
  }
};

// View Section to show and get items

var events = {
  addItem : function(){
    var itemInputValue = document.getElementById("addItemInput");
    todoListArray.addItems(itemInputValue.value);
    todoListArray.displayItems();
    itemInputValue.value = "";
  }
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in displayItems, you can reset the `listParent`, so every time you click button will show one array's list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `displayItems` you are iterating through the entire list from the beginning and appending each item. Hence when you run through `displayItems` a 2nd, 3rd, ... time you are appending the entire list.

You would either need to (a) keep track of the last item you have already displayed, or (b) remove the displayed list of `li`'s entirely before iterating through `todoList` again.

```
var todoListArray = {
  lastIndex : 0, // last todoList index we have displayed
  ...
  displayItems : function(){
    var listParent = document.getElementById('todoList');

    // start with i=this.lastIndex to pick up where we left off
    for(var i=this.lastIndex; i<this.todoList.length; i++){
      var listItem = document.createElement('li');
      listItem.innerHTML = this.todoList[i].todoItem;
      listParent.appendChild(listItem);
      this.lastIndex++; // increment the last index once it is displayed
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Yes it is right. I was looping through with the wrong defined variable. Thanks a lot.